# List channel messages API does not list all messages

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

It seems [list channel messages API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list-messages) does not lists all messages, specifically it does not list messages which are automatically posted when "Meet" button is pressed. When "Meet" button is pressed, it starts meetings, thus users can reply to the thread. We would like to find a way to capture such information using Graph APIs

Such messages are not returned by Graph API:
[image]

Comment: Hi @vikbehal, Checking internally on this will keep you posted as soon as possible.

Comment: Could we please get on call to discuss, seems this is not supported by graph API at present moment. Please write to us at microsoftteamsdev@microsoft.com

Answer (score 0):

Conversations/replies to “Meet Now”(channel meeting) aren’t considered as channel messages since, user isn’t posting a message to channel. If the user is posting a new message to channel using “New Conversation Button” it’s considered as channel message.

Now, chat message API works because there is scope of chat replies  for that particular message as a result we are also getting the replies back.

These  features discussed above are by design.